# JAVA 8 : HOW TO MERGE TWO LIST USING 2 STREAM

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Hello I wrote the following code

```
for (Object1 o1 : listObject1) {
  boolean found = false;
  for (Object2 o2 : listObject2) {
    found = o2.getKey().equals(o1.getKey());
    if (found) break;
  }
  if (!found) listObject2.add(new Object2(o1.getKey()));
}
```

But I want to write it in Java 8 using streams. I tried to use flatMap but I did not succeed. Can someone help me ? and explain to me the use of flatmap ?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Plug your entire title into Google search and you will have plenty of reading with examples.

Comment: You are calling listObject2.add, its called mutating the list. since streams in java are an attempt to mimic  functional programming  which is immutable by nature I don't think Its a good idea for you to use it in this case, because the output of a stream creates a new list.

Comment: @PM77-1 Usually very good advice, but in this case title probably doesn't describe what OP really is trying to achieve (at least based on code example).

Comment: @PM77-1 before posting this article i searched but i dont found an example with my case

Comment: The way I read it, OP wants to concatenate and then de-duplicate two streams.

Comment: There's nothing to be gained by converting this to streams.  It's fine as two loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to improve readability then IMO biggest gain you will get is not via streams but via caching keys of elements from second list (it can be done via streams if you want)

```
Set<String> keysInList2 = listObject2.stream()
                                     .map(Object2::getKey)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you can `add` to that set another key of object from listObject1, then it means such key was not yet present in set. In such case you should also add new Object2 element with such key to `listObject2`

```
for (Object1 o1 : listObject1) {
    if (keysInList2.add(o1.getKey())){
        listObject2.add(new Object2(o1.getKey()));
    }
}
```